# How update an a component called many times in App.js React?

Tags: reactjs, dashboard, react-component, recharts

I am preparing a dashboard with multiple charts, inside exist many charts of the same type (BarChart or PieChart...etc), this means that the component that paints the bar chart is called many times, a different id is assigned for each one. My problem is the filtering.

If I filter on a chart, all of them should be filtered, I am using componentDidUpdate to change the url of the charts (new state) which allows me to filter by adding an fq (field-query). The drawback is that when filtering, only the chart I clicked is filtered and not all the others, which is how it should work.

If the new state of the component has the filter in componentDidUpdate (filters comes from session storage ),why only filtered the chart that I clicked, if they all use the same code?

Another question is how to transfer adequately filters between different types of chart (Pie, Line)?sessionStorage?

all my components are declared as class and the idea is not to rewrite them to use hooks or redux...too late.

every panel contain one chart

#### Panels.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Bars from '../Graphs/BARS/Modules';

class Panel extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          core: '',
          description: '',
          title: '',
          mode: 'count',
          facet: '',
          colors: [],
          limit: 10,
          graph: '',
          grap2:'',
          id: '',
          isLoaded: false,
        }
        this.handleInit = this.handleInit(props)
    }
    handleInit (props) {
        
        const url = 'https://buscador.creangel.com/proxyreact/acceso/creangel/solrDash30/panelsGen/select?rows=1&fq=id:"'+props.id+'"';
        
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                let result = response.data.response.docs[0];
                let mode = 'count'
                let facet = ''
                let graph = 'None'
                let graph2 = 'None'
                let limit = 10
                try{ mode = result.mode[0]; }catch{}
                try{ facet = result.facet[0]; }catch{}
                try{ graph = result.panel[0]; }catch{}
                try{ limit = result.limit[0]; }catch{}
                this.setState({
                    core: result.core[0],
                    description: result.description[0],
                    title: result.title[0],
                    mode: mode,
                    facet: facet,
                    colors: result.colors[0],
                    limit: limit,
                    graph: graph,
                    grap2: graph2,
                    isLoaded: true
                })
        })
    }
  /*componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }*/
    render(){
        let Graph = ''
        let Graph2  = ''
        if(this.state.isLoaded){
            if(this.state.graph.indexOf('BAR')!==-1){
            Graph = <Bars.BAR01V id={this.props.id} data={this.state} details={this.state} ></Bars.BAR01V>; 
            //Graph = <Bars.PIE01 id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.PIE01>;
            //Graph = <Bars.LINE01S id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.LINE01S>;
            }
            else if(this.state.graph.indexOf('LINE')!==0){
                //Graph = <Bars.BAR01V id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.BAR01V>;    
                //Graph = <Bars.PIE01 id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.PIE01>;
                //Graph = <Bars.LINE01S id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.LINE01S>;
                }
            if(this.state.graph.indexOf('PIE')!==0){
                //Graph = <Bars.BAR01V id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.BAR01V>;    
                //Graph = <Bars.PIE01 id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.PIE01>;
                //Graph = <Bars.LINE01S id={this.props.id} data={this.state} ></Bars.LINE01S>;
                }   
        }
    
        return (
                <Col sm={this.props.panelSize} className="h-100 dashPanel radius border panel-resizable">
                {this.props.panelSize} - {this.props.id} - {this.state.graph} {Graph}
            
                </Col>
                
            );

    }
}
export default Panel;
```

#### BAR01V.js

```
import React, {Component, useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
//import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
//import { connect, useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { BarChart , Bar } from 'recharts';
import {    CartesianGrid,
            XAxis,
            YAxis,
            Tooltip,
            Legend,
            ResponsiveContainer,
            LabelList
} from 'recharts';
import CustomTooltip from '../CustomTooltip';

class BAR01V extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        
        super(props)
        var facetfield = props.data.facet
        this.state = {
            data: '',
            url: 'https://buscador.creangel.com/proxyreact/acceso/creangel/Data36/'+props.data.core+'/select?facet=on&json.facet={'+facetfield+":{type:terms,limit:"+props.data.limit+ ",field:" + facetfield + "}}",
            isLoaded: true,
            details: false

        }
    
        //window.addEventListener('storage',  (e) =>  {
        //      })  
            
        this.handleInit = this.handleInit(props)
        
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)  
            
    }   
    
        componentDidMount(){            

        }


        componentDidUpdate() {
            //window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => {
                
            //})

            if (this.state.details === true ) 
            {

            var facetfield = this.props.data.facet;
            var urlFiltered = sessionStorage.getItem('url') + sessionStorage.getItem('urlFragment')
            console.log(urlFiltered)
            axios.get(urlFiltered)
                 .then(response => {
                let data = []
                let facets = response.data.facets[facetfield].buckets
                for (let i in facets){
                    let slice = {
                        "name":facets[i].val,
                        "count":facets[i].count
        
                    };
                     data.push(slice);
                    
                }
                
                this.setState({
                    data: data,
                    isLoaded: true,
                    details: false
                })      
        
        })
            
    }else{

    }   
        
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            
            window.removeEventListener();
        }
            
    handleInit(props){  
        
        var facetfield = props.data.facet   
        console.log(this.state.url)

        axios.get(this.state.url)       
            .then(response => {
                let data = []
                let facets = response.data.facets[facetfield].buckets
                for (let i in facets){
                    let slice = {
                        "name":facets[i].val,
                        "count":facets[i].count

                    };
                     data.push(slice);
                    
                }
                
                this.setState({
                    data: data,
                    isLoaded: true
                    
                })
                

        })
        
                
        
    }
    handleClick(e) {
                
        var facetfield = this.props.data.facet      
        let filters = []
        let indexfilter = [];
        
        console.log(e)
        this.setState({
            justClicked: e.target,
            filter: e.activeLabel,
            url: 'https://buscador.creangel.com/proxyreact/acceso/creangel/Data36/'+this.props.data.core+'/select?facet=on&json.facet={'+facetfield+":{type:terms,limit:"+this.props.data.limit+ ",field:" + facetfield + "}}",
            urlFragment: '&fq='+facetfield+':'+ e.activeLabel,
            parent : this.props.data.facet,
            letter : e.activeLabel,
            details: true
            });         
            
    sessionStorage.setItem('url', this.state.url)
    sessionStorage.setItem('urlFragment', '&fq='+facetfield+':'+ e.activeLabel)
    sessionStorage.setItem('parent', this.props.data.facet)
    sessionStorage.setItem('letter', e.activeLabel);
    
    //let event = new Event('storage');
    //  window.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
                  
render(){           
    
        let width = ($('#'+this.props.id).width());
        let height = ($('#'+this.props.id).height());
        
        return (        

            <ResponsiveContainer id={this.props.id}  width="80%" height="80%">
                <BarChart width={730} height={250} data={this.state.data} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                    <XAxis dataKey="name" />
                    <YAxis />
                    <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />}/>
                    <Bar dataKey="count" fill="#8884d8" >
                    </Bar>
                </BarChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
        );
    }   
}

export default BAR01V;
```